# How to set steps in HTML input type=time

Tags: android, ios, html, input, ionic-framework

I'm currently building an app using the Ionic-Framework. To set a timer I used the HTML input and set the type to "time".
Is there any way, to set the step size of the native "time picker"? e.g. instead of 17:01, 17:02, 17:03 to have 17:00, 17:15, 17:30 ...